# Samsung Galaxy S heat up a lot, getting restarted and slow start up time

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, reboot

I'm using Samsung galaxy S with O.S. 2.3.3. I'm having the following problems.
It is getting heated up a lot. Because of this the battery is drained so faster.
That too when it is getting charged if I place butter it melts down.
It is also getting restarted whenever there is an exception in the app.
I'm having a lot of applications so the start up time is very slow around 3 - 8 minutes to load.

Comment: Are you running a custom ROM?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a battery drainer App which also heats up the CPU by holding a wakelock and using the CPU the whole time. You need to identify and remove that App.

The Galaxy S has a pretty nice App called "program manager", also using Androids built-in "what caused the most battery consumption" feature should help you to find this App.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have a lot of apps. Are a lot of them running in the background? If so, they could be the cause of your issues. It could be also possible that you have a virus, or you have an anti-virus (which could be eating up a lot of CPU processes).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and found that the problem is the memory card. If I remove the memory card, the phone is good — battery back up and run with out heating up.

Comment: The SDCard alone wouldn't be that much of an hassle, perhaps an app that uses the memory card when is available? Have you checked the running processes to confirm that nothing is using the memory card when it is available?